# Save fb/google profile picture

Tags: django, django-allauth, cookiecutter

I'm using django cookie cutter which has pre-installed django-allauth. I've integrated fb and google to login successfully. But I need to save profile picture returned by fb/google in my user model. 
But I can't find where django-allauth saves data in user model so that I can save profile pic as well.

Has somebody used it or know where can I edit this code?

Comment: Please add a few more details/code/ etc

Comment: Code wouldn't help here as django-allauth is a standard package for social login

Answer (score 2):

From the sound of it (I don't use it) django-allauth is an authentication wrapper that provides some convenience functions to various APIs - what makes you think it is storing aspects like the profile picture at all? I think what you want is the ProviderAccount get_avatar_url() [[1]](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/7b00fdc596e6f48409114262e236b98db0464cf4/allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/provider.py#L36)[[2]](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/7b00fdc596e6f48409114262e236b98db0464cf4/allauth/socialaccount/providers/google/provider.py#L18,) then request and save it yourself. If you want it to be connected to the User model then a [profile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) is probably the way to go. Avoid a custom user model unless it is absolutely necessary (which since you have started a project with cookiecutter, I can assume it is not).

Comment: I've created a profile model only and linked that with User model using foreign key. I know about  get_avatar_url() to return profile picture. But my question is how can i retrieve this profile pic? and should i save this in my User model or profile model?

Comment: I've found the solution. But any idea how to get fb profile picture during fb login?

Comment: @AjaySingh I'm not sure what you mean exactly - if you want to get the profile picture when a user logs in you could add that to the view that logs the user in.

Comment: you indirectly helped me. Thanks :)